# Point label only partially visible in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I want to add a label to the following plot, but due to the axes being small I can only see a part of it. Is there a way of adding "virtual space" to the plot so I can see the whole label? It is quite evident that increasing `xmax` will do the trick, but the plot is already too big for the document it will sit in, so I'm looking for another approach. I've already tried:

- Changing the font size.
- Arranging it as a "column" vector with a `pmatrix` env.

But the results are visually awful. I included a screencap of the output after the code. Thanks!!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    ymax=1.3,
    ymin=-1.3,
    xmax=1.3,
    xmin=-1.3,
    trig format plots=rad,
    declare function = {C(\x)=cos(\x); S(\x)=sin(\x);},
]
    \addplot[domain=-pi:pi,samples=100,red,thick] ({C(x)},{S(x)});
    \addplot[->] coordinates {(0,0) ({C(pi/4)},{S(pi/4)})};
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {({C(pi/4)},{S(pi/4)})} node[anchor=south west] {(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}),\sen(\frac{\pi}{4}))};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You just need the `clip=false` option.  Also, thanks for posting a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301. But, for future reference, please make it complate by including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. And, also make it compilable.

Comment: @PeterGrill Right, I just copied and pasted from the document code; my apologies. Could you please move your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Will do, but please try compiling the code as is and you'll find that does not compile due to the missing `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the option `clip=false`, the label won't be cut off:

[image]

### Notes

- I think the `-latex` produces a better arrouw for this case, so I used that instead of `->`.
- The MWE as given was missing the `$` required around the `node` text.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    ymax=1.3,
    ymin=-1.3,
    xmax=1.3,
    xmin=-1.3,
    trig format plots=rad,
    declare function = {C(\x)=cos(\x); S(\x)=sin(\x);},
    clip=false
]
    \addplot[domain=-pi:pi,samples=100,red,thick] ({C(x)},{S(x)});
    \addplot[-latex] coordinates {(0,0) ({C(pi/4)},{S(pi/4)})};
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {({C(pi/4)},{S(pi/4)})} 
        node[anchor=south west] {$(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}),\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))$};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```